# Why I am getting this error in Laravel? Error:-Too few arguments to function Darryldecode\Cart\Cart::updateQuantityRelative()

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I am getting this error:

> ArgumentCountError
> Too few arguments to function Darryldecode\Cart\Cart::updateQuantityRelative(), 1 passed in ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 261 and exactly 3 expected (View: ...\resources\views\cart.blade.php)

**cart.blade.php**

```
@foreach(\Cart::session(auth()->id())->getContent() as $items)
   <tr>
     <td class="text-center">
       <a href="{{ route('cart.destroy', $items->id)}}">x</a>
       </td>
        <td data-title="Product">
          <a href="#" class="text-gray-90">{{ $items ['name'] }}</a>
        </td>
       <td data-title="Price">
          <span class="">LKR {{ $items ['price'] }}.00</span>
       </td>
       <td data-title="Quantity">
            <span class="sr-only">Quantity</span>
       <!-- Quantity -->
               <div class="border rounded-pill py-1 width-122 w-xl-80 px-3 border-color-1">
                  <div class="js-quantity row align-items-center">
                      <div class="col">
                          <input class="js-result form-control h-auto border-0 rounded p-0 shadow-none" type="text" value="{{ \Cart::updateQuantityRelative($items->quantity) }}">
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-auto pr-1">
                              <a class="js-minus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                  <small class="fas fa-minus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                </a>
                               <a class="js-plus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                    <small class="fas fa-plus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                  </a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                         </div> 
       <!-- End Quantity -->
      </td>
      <td data-title="Total">
          <span class="">
               {{ $items -> getPriceSum()}}
            </span>
        </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

**CartController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;
use Darryldecode\Cart\Cart;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('cart');
    }
   
    public function show($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        return view('cart')->with(compact('product'));
    }
   
    public function destroy($itemId)
    {
       return back();
    }

    public function addtocart(Product $product)
    {
    
        \Cart::session(auth()->id())->add(array(
            'id' => $product->id,
            'name' => $product->prod_name,
            'price' => $product->prod_price,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'attributes' => array(),
            'associatedModel' => $product
        ));

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

I installed *Darryldecode* shopping cart package.

This `updateQuantityRelative` function is defined in it.

```
public function updateQuantityRelative($item, $key, $value)
{
    if (preg_match('/\-/', $value) == 1) {
        $value = (int)str_replace('-', '', $value);

        // we will not allowed to reduced quantity to 0, so if the given value
        // would result to item quantity of 0, we will not do it.
        if (($item[$key] - $value) > 0) {
            $item[$key] -= $value;
        }
    } elseif (preg_match('/\+/', $value) == 1) {
        $item[$key] += (int)str_replace('+', '', $value);
    } else {
        $item[$key] += (int)$value;
    }

    return $item;
}
```

I think the below code is to be corrected. How it should be?

```
value="{{ \Cart::updateQuantityRelative($items->quantity) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.
Added a button as Update Cart.

```
<form action="{{route('cart.update',$items->id)}}">
                                                        <div class="d-md-flex">
                                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-soft-secondary mb-3 mb-md-0 font-weight-normal px-5 px-md-4 px-lg-5 w-100 w-md-auto">Update cart</button>
                                                            <a href="../shop/checkout.html" class="btn btn-primary-dark-w ml-md-2 px-5 px-md-4 px-lg-5 w-100 w-md-auto d-none d-md-inline-block">Proceed to checkout</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
```

And change the total as,

```
                                <td data-title="Total">
                                    <span class="">
                                          {{Cart::session(auth()->id())->get($items->id)->getPriceSum()}}
                                    </span>
                                </td>
```

As well as corrected this too,

```
<input class="js-result form-control h-auto border-0 rounded p-0 shadow-none" type="text" value="{{$items->quantity}}"
```